# How to loop with different values in T-SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have some specific set of values that I want to filter on a column, I don't want to do an 'in' clause in SQL Server. I want to use loop to pass in different set of values each time.

For example if there is a name column in my data, and I want to run query 5 times with different filter value.

Please look at the loop query attached below.

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 1;

WHILE @cnt < 94
BEGIN
    SELECT Name, COUNT(*) AS Number_of_Names 
    FROM Table
    WHERE name IN ('John')
      AND value IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY Name

    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;
```

I want to pass in different values under 'name' column at each loop like john in the case above, then mary in the next loop likewise based on set of values I pass in the variable like `@values = John,Mary,Nicole,matt` etc..

Comment: SQL is a set-based language. Loops aren't needed in the vast majority of cases. Your code doesn't to anything special either, it just repeats the same query. What are you trying to do? Whatever it is, it can be done *without* loops

Comment: For example instead of `run query 5 times with different filter value.`, run a *single* query that checks for all values,eg `where name in ('Joe','John','Jack','George','Mike')`

Comment: *"I don't want to do in clause...  ...I want to do loops"* I can't imagine a good reason to go this route though. Why do you not want to use an "IN" condition? There's no scenario where it wouldn't be MUCH faster than a loop.

Comment: hhhmmmm.....you want to run 94 queries instead of 1? Either you haven't explained this very well or this is an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @panagiotis That's true but when that value that I am looking for might not exist it wont show up in results

Comment: @Ahmed the loop won't return any results either. Explain the actual problem , not how you think it can be solved. Whatever it is, loops aren't the solution

Comment: @panagiotis Ok.Thanks!
 In that case will create a temp table with these values and do a join on it.

Comment: @Ahmed, you did not really describe, what you want to achieve, but I get the feeling, that you want to count the Johns, the Marys, the Nicoles and so on. Correct? If so, you should read about `GROUP BY` and aggregate functions, in your case `COUNT()`. You can combine this with a list of names either through a list in an `IN`-clause or - if this list is a set - with an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the comments on your question, this should give you an idea on how to achieve a solution without using loops and still get all the names even when the name is not present on the table.

```
SELECT Name, 
    COUNT(value) AS Number_of_Names --Only count when value is not null
FROM (VALUES('John'), ('Mary'), ('Nicole'), ('Matt'))Names(name) --This can be replaced by a table-valued parameter or temp table.
LEFT JOIN Table t ON Names.name = t.name
--WHERE name IN ('John') /*No longer needed*/
--AND value IS NOT NULL /*Removed this because it would make the OUTER JOIN behave as an INNER JOIN*/
GROUP BY Name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Luis!